# Add table at the bottom of last page without using footer

Tags: html, css, freemarker

I'm using html and FreeMarker in order to create a pdf.

I have to print many pages and add a table on the bottom part of the last page.
I'm already using a footer on each page

```
<body header="nlheader" header-height="180px" footer="nlfooter" footer-height="80px" padding="0.5in 0.5in 0.5in 0.5in" size="A4">
<table class="body" style="width: 100%; margin-top: 10px;">
    <#--- Body table --->
</table>

<table class="recap">
    <#--- Table to keep at the bottom --->
</table>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot of ways to do this, but this is the best one I think, I also use it personally:

1. make sure html and body have 100% height
2. wrap the two tables in a **div** and give it **display: flex;** with  **flex-direction: column;** and **justify-content: space-between;**
3. give the **div** a height of the available space (100% - footer height)

Check out the snippet bellow:

```css
*{/* those only to remove margins */
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
html,body{/* make sure to give html and body 100% height */
  height:100%;
}
.container{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  justify-content:space-between;
  height: calc(100% - 45px); /* 100% - footer height (thats the available space)*/
  /* Change the 45px to the footer height */
}
footer{/* footer sample */
  height:45px;
  background-color:#223;
  color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div class="container">
<table class="body" style="width: 100%; margin-top: 10px;">
    <td><#--- Body table ---></td>
</table>

<table class="recap">
    <td><#--- Table to keep at the bottom ---></td>
</table>
</div>
<footer>This is the footer</footer>
</body>
</html>
```